# Fixed Gate Time on the MIDI region doesnt provide staccato over the full region

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro, articulation

My problem is that I have a MIDI region (few bars of unquantized chords on every beat). I have set the Gate Time in the Inspector to Fixed and waht I get is only some notes are getting staccato, some stays unchanged. I don't think it's an expected behaviour, but I'm not sure because I'm just learning this stuff. Can anybody tell me how is it really suppose to work, and what can be the issue, how to solve it in my Logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out :) I have normalized the track and realised then that notes are in fact getting shorter, so the problem must have been elsewhere. I totally forgot that I have **sustain automation** recorded for that region, and wherever sustain "catch" the short notes it have had prolonged them. Removing automation totally resolved the issue.